# Base64Encoding result string with "/" in Swift

Tags: swift, string, base64

I want to convert a UIImage to a string representation. I am using the following code:

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage)

if let imageBase64 = imageData?.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions (rawValue: 0)) {
    let strBase64:String = imageBase64.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
}
```

The resulting string looks something like:

> 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

But the format I am looking for should contain "/", like the following (a random image I found):

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUSEhMWFRUWGBcZGRgXFxcVFRgYFxUWFhcVFxgYHSggGBolGxcXITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGhAQGisdHx0tLS0tKy0tLS0tLSstLS0tLS0tLS0tKy0tLS0tLSstLS0tLSs3Ky0tKysrLSstKysrK//AABEIAMwAzAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAABBAMBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAgMEBQABBwj/xABCEAABAwIDBQUGAwYFBAMBAAABAgMRAAQSITEFBkFRYRMicYGRBzJCobHRFCPBUmKCk+HwM0NTctIVkqLxRGOyJP/

I don't know how to get the second format (containing the "/").

Comment: What exactly do you **need** the slashes for? They don't have any special meaning, they're just one part of the encoded data, not unlike the other symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're encoding it twice. Just do

```
let strBase64 = imageData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

Comment: yeah, that's a valid point. However, the result still does not contain any "/", after I applied what you proposed.

Comment: @user2840482 Base-64 encoding doesn't always produce slashes.